# Firebase Rules cannot read UserID in array

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, flutterflow

I am very new to Firebase and use FlutterFlow to build a basic UI for now. I run into a understanding problem where I dont know what I am doing wrong.

In a collection, named organizations, I have the following:
[image]
The overall goal is that all auth-userIDs in members can Read,Write and Delete this organization.

If I set the rules in Firebase to

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{document} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == document;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == document;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == document;
      allow delete: if false;
    }

    match /organizations/{document} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
      allow delete: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

My UI renders all items in the collection, all good. If I change now the Read Write Delete to Tagged Users (the term the flutter UI uses)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{document} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == document;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == document;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == document;
      allow delete: if false;
    }

    match /organizations/{document} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
    }
  }
}
```

I no longer get any organization back. I added the auth userID manual in the organization>users in the formats of /users/XXXXXX or just XXXXXXX taken from the users/{documentsIDs} but makes no difference.

What am I doing wrong?

In the GCP query builder I get the same issue:
Works on field directly with an ID
[image]

Does not work on the arrary of members
[image]

Comment: What is the of the `users` field inside the document? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo, added an image. To note, I also moved users to members in the meantime. Question updated accourdingly. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It pens out that the rule it self was okey (has evolved a bit since then)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{document} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == document;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == document;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == document;
      allow delete: if false;
    }

    match /organizations/{document} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow read: if resource.data.created_by == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);
      allow write: if resource.data.created_by == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);
      allow delete: if resource.data.created_by == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);
    }
  }
}
```

But given this statement from:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_authuid

> The query fails even if the current user actually is the author of every story document. The reason for this behavior is that when Cloud Firestore applies your security rules, it evaluates the query against its potential result set, not against the actual properties of documents in your database. If a query could potentially include documents that violate your security rules, the query will fail.

If loading the documents list, it must be filtered to not violate the above.

Answer (score 0):

In your second screenshot you're using an `in` operator, which checks if the singular value of the field on the left hand side (`members` in your case) is contained within the array of values you specify in the right hand side. Since `members` is an array, it checks for an array inside the array on the right-hand side, which is not what you want.

You're looking for the [`array-contains` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), which checks whether the singular value you specify on the right hand side is present in the array field you specify on the left hand side.

---

Unrelated: the `create` rule for an `organization` is incorrect. The `resource.data` contains the values of the document *before* the write operation, so it will always be empty for `create`. You'll want to use `request.resource.data`, which contains the values as they'll exist after the write operation (if it's allowed).

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for taking your time.
I am not sure how this helps me to set the rules correct, I still dont know what to do. I also tried not to simplify the conditions and put the below but still no list

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /organizations/{document} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.createdBy;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.createdBy;
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.createdBy;
    }

Comment: You asked "What am I doing wrong?" in your question, and I answered by pointing out why the last screenshot in your question doesn't work. Since you claim that this is the same issue as in your FlutterFlow app, I assume you'll need to make the same change (using `array-contains` rather than `in`) there.